React.cache() with an object
Following the docs we understand that we can use the cache function like this:
const getTemperature = cache(async (city) => {
    return await fetchTemperature(city);
});

async function AnimatedWeatherCard({city}) {
    const temperature = await getTemperature(city);
    // ...
}

The city parameter act as a cache key so if it's the same then the fetch will not to be triggered another time.
In my case it's a bit different because the parameter of the cache function is an object.
type User = { id: string, name: string, email: string }

const getUser = cache(async (user: User) => {
    return await fetchUser(user);
});

async function AnimatedUserCard({user}) {
    const user = await getuser(user);
    // ...
}

The problem I have is that even though the user is the same, the object is not because it's reference is different hence making the fetch call run twice instead  of once.
EDIT: My specific case (doesn't get cached obviously)
import { cache } from "react"

interface GraphqlRequestParameters<T, V> {
  document: RequestDocument | TypedDocumentNode<T, V>
  variables?: V
  withAuth?: boolean
  requestHeaders?: GraphQLClientRequestHeaders
  onError?: (error: unknown) => void
}

export async function graphqlServerRequest<T, V extends Variables = Variables>({
  document,
  variables,
  withAuth = false,
  requestHeaders,
  onError,
}: GraphqlRequestParameters<T, V>): Promise<T | undefined> {
  try {
    if (withAuth) {
      return await graphqlServerWithAuth.request(document, variables, requestHeaders)
    } else {
      return await graphqlServerWithoutAuth.request(document, variables, requestHeaders)
    }
  } catch (error) {
    if (onError) onError(error)
    else throw error
  }
}

export const cachedGraphqlServerRequest = cache(graphqlServerRequest)

used like this:
// page.tsx

  await cachedGraphqlServerRequest({
    document: someQuery,
    withAuth: true,
    variables: { slug },
    onError() {
      notFound()
    },
  })

  await cachedGraphqlServerRequest({
    document: someQuery,
    withAuth: true,
    variables: { slug },
    onError() {
      notFound()
    },
  })


I don't think there is much that can be done here, unless you change your approach. 1. Maybe pass just userId and create your user inside the cached function if possible. 2. Maybe stringify the object to make it a primitve and then pass it as argument and parse it inside. 2nd approach is worse than the 1st one

If you can show where the different use references are maybe we can make try to merge them into one
